# Testing React Component: Expected Function Call Not Detected

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs

I'm having trouble testing a React component where I expect a certain function to be called, but it's not being detected by my test. I've reviewed my code, and everything seems to be set up correctly. Here are the details of my problem:

I have a React component, let's call it **`YourComponent`**, which has a button that triggers the **`handleCompleteClick`** function when clicked. Within **`handleCompleteClick`**, I expect the **`updateStatus`** function to be called with the argument **`'COMPLETED'`**.

Here's the relevant part of **`YourComponent`**:

```
const handleCompleteClick = (event) => {
  console.log('INSIDE COMPLETE');
  const newStatus = 'COMPLETED';
  event.stopPropagation();
  updateStatus(newStatus);
};


it('should call updateStatus with "COMPLETED"', () => {
  const mockupdateStatus = jest.fn();

  const wrapper = mount(
    <YourComponent updateStatus={mockupdateStatus} />
  );

  const MenuItems = wrapper2.find('MockMenuItems');
    const mockEvent = { stopPropagation: jest.fn() };

    MenuItems.prop('CompleteClick');
    MenuItems.prop('CompleteClick')(mockEvent);
    wrapper2.update();});

  await act(async () => {
      wrapper2.update();
      expect(mockupdateStatus).toHaveBeenCalledWith('COMPLETED');
    });
```

ISSUE:

The problem I'm facing is that when I run this test, it fails with the following message:

```
Expected: "COMPLETED"
Number of calls: 0
```

Comment: Can you show the full code of the component under test?